# PHP - SQL - DateTime not prompted out

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

**Aim**

To echo the datetime from a column inside a database based on the token entered.

**Database**

[image]

**Codes**

```
<?php
    include("config_new.php");
    include("dbconnection.php");

    $homepage = "index.php"; 

    if(isset($_GET["token"])){
        $token=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['token']);
        $expiryDate ="SELECT * from dateData WHERE token='$token'";
        $exDate=mysqli_query($conn,$expiryDate);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($exDate)>0){
            $tkDate=mysqli_fetch_assoc($exDate);
            $tokenDate=$tkDate['tokenDate'];
            //$expiryTokenDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d',strtotime($tokenDate). "+1 hour));
            echo $tokenDate;
            echo 'Hello';
        }
    }else{
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

        <title>FYP - Password Reset</title>

        <link href="res/css/stylish-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="res/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]

I have tried to echo the `$tokenDate` but when nothing appeared I thought that it was because nothing was being passed through. So I included `echo 'Hello';` and the "Hello" was prompted at the top of the webpage which means it does pass through the codes.

I have tried changing the `$tokenDate=$tkDate['tokenDate']` to `$tokenDate=$tkDate["tokenDate"]` but still nothing appeared. If the wrong token is entered, the user will be redirected to the index page. This shows that the if else statement is working.

**Desired Output**

2018-01-04 09:16:19

Hello

I would like to have the date from the **tokenDate** based on the token entered to be prompted out.

**Error**

Nothing appears within the developer tool and there is no error prompted. The only thing prompted is the word "Hello".

**Work Flow**

index.php -> forgotPassword.php(Generates Token) --Existing Token--> resetPassword.php

**Explanation**

The resetPassword.php can only be access by having the user enter an existing URL (Token). Once there, the resetPassword.php will `GET` the token and the if else statement will check

**Question**

How can I echo/prompt the data within the tokenDate based on the token?

---

**Solution**

I was able to echo the specific datetime based on the entered **token** by using the codes below.

```
if(isset($_GET["token"])){

$token=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['token']);
$sql=("SELECT tokenDate from pha_user WHERE token like '%$token%'");
$sqltran=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$tokenDate= mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqltran);
$starttime = new DateTime($tokenDate["tokenDate"]);

    $expiryTokenDate=$starttime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $expiryTokenDate;
```

**Explanation**

1. After getting the "token", an SQL statement is used to search for any tokenDate which contains the `$token` variable.
2. The `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will functions by fetching the result row and set it as variable `$tokenDate`.
3. Once there, the DateTime() function will convert it into PHP DateTime format and set it as variable `$starttime`.
4. After that, I changed the `$starttime` variable into my desired format which is `('Y-m-d H:i:s')` and set it as `$expiryTokenDate`, and echo it.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the question. The only thing I can get out of it would be my asking what value should `$_GET['token']` be. A URL or an actual token? You do know what those are, right?

Comment: You're code does not do what you expect. If an invalid token is entered, it will _not_ redirect the user. It will simply not find a match but still echo "hello". You're only redirecting the user if no token is present at all.

Comment: and did you even connect to your database? there are too many things that are starting to be unclear.

Comment: and seeing a previous question of yours, are you using JS with this also? well, you can @Niner me if you want, *ciao!*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner its an url. And when I enter an existing URL(Token) it does display the webpage to the user but when the wrong URL(Token) is entered, the index page is displayed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson when I enter an existing URL(Token) it does display the webpage to the user but when the wrong URL(Token) is entered, the index page is displayed. And no it does not echo a "Hello" it simply does not show the page therefore no "Hello" is prompted.

Comment: I get it now (I think). You need to either check if a row exists, or use a comparison method.

Comment: Oh, is it like `if(mysqli_num_rows($exDate)>0){` I will try it out now. No I'm not using JS with this.

Comment: _"it does display the webpage"_ What webpage? `if(isset($_GET["token"]))` only checks if `$_GET['token']` exists and isn't null. It has nothing to do with if it exists in your db. Is this all your code or is there more going on behind the scenes?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The `if(isset($_GET["token"]))` is on `resetPassword.php` file which will only display if the file `GET` the token enetred.

Comment: That doesn't clarify much at all. Please clarify your question and add _all_ relevant information and code. Remember that we know absolutely nothing about your app/code and can't see your screen. We are 100% dependent on your explanation.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Noted, I will edit the question and add more codes. I'll try to explain my problem better.

Comment: Answered his own question.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting assigning the `$starttime` into PHP DateTime format. Then use the $starttime and turn it into ('Y-m-d H:i:s') format.

Comment: Thanks Bill but I have already written the solution in my question but I'll still accept your answer.